# Magento - Get attribute value per website

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've created (manually via Admin Panel) an attribute called `att_by_website` which is scoped as 'Website' and I'm want to get its several values.

How can I do this? I'm able to set different values via Admin Panel, but at this time I'm only able to get the default value.

When I execute `$this->getProduct()->getData('att_by_website')` it returns only the default value (where `$this->getProduct()` returns an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`).

Thanks!

Comment: You should set store id to product model before invoking load. I.e. `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(<needed id>)->load()`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I don't believe this is what I need. getProduct() already points to the product itself, this means that I don't need to query against DB again.

Comment: Is the attribute scope set to website? Perhaps you are querying global attributes.

Comment: I've edited the post to add more info. Regarding the first comment (from @Zyava): will setStoreId help me considering I'm dealing with several websites (instead of stores)?

Comment: No, you can set product value per store => you must set store id before loading product, otherwise current store id will be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be the best approach, but solved the problem:

```
$value = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productID, 'att_by_website', $storeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    $websiteId = $website->getWebsiteId();
    $storeId = $website->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);

    echo $this->getProduct()->getData('att_by_website');
}
```